# Is it possible to set The Secret World to remember and auto-join a Custom Chat channel?

Tags: the-secret-world

I'm playing **The Secret World** along with a bunch of folks from a community of which I'm a member. We haven't bothered to form a Cabal because we have people playing as part of all three Societies, and because historically, we've tended to use chat channels in most games whenever available. **TSW** supports custom channels, and we have one and it's great, except for one little problem.

Every time I log in, I need to rejoin the channel.

Is there any way to make this a persistent preference so that I don't need to type `/chat join #SeekritClubhouse Password` every time I log in? Because that would be awesome and make my life so much easier.

Answer (score 3):

The chat is currently very buggy. The subscription information get lost on relog and on switching zones. This should get fixed soon.

But there **may** be a way:

- Create the folder "Scripts" in your The Secret World folder.
- Create the two files "auto_login" and "auto_teleport" (WITHOUT any extension) with an editor in the Script folder.
- Add the chat join command into both text files and save the files.

The "auto_login" will get executed on login and "auto_teleport" on zone changes.

Comment: Tried the Scripts folder trick today. Did not work. :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to comment on the answer above, but it was actually very close to correct:

All that's needed is to create the auto_login file with the line:

/chat join *channel_name*

Worked like a charm for me.